# Why spring-data-redis JedisClusterConnection does not supports pipeline for Redis Cluster?

Tags: spring-data-redis

We are using spring-data-redis and Jedis for our application. We require some **hmget** for multiple keys in single request on Redis Cluster then we tried to do it with pipeline feature. But we found that spring-data-redis does not supports the pipeline for Redis Cluster if we use **JedisClusterConnection**.

Can someone help me out to provide some information related to do pipeline operation on Redis Cluster? Can we get this feature in future with new release?

Right now, we tried to implement pipeline in our code. For that we require some Jedis connection from jedis pool. so we did it by getting JedisCluster native connection from JedisClusterConnection. Now we require Jedis connection from JedisCluster but JedisCluster does not provides connection handler to get connection from slot. For that I already raised the Pull Request in Jedis library and waiting for Review.

Comment: I do not know about this feature will be available in spring-data-redis but as per my understanding and redis group discussion. Jedis library not provides this feature because there could chances of slot movement during execution of pipeline operation on redis cluster. That may cause the data inconsistency due to failure operation. Here is the discussion between Redis group and Jedis community developer. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/redis-db/4I0ELYnf3bk/Lrctk0ULm6AJ

Comment: Still they are not able to overcome with this issue. So i am thinking due to this reason spring-data-redis not provides the pipeline on redis cluster. But my suggestion to spring-data-redis community can you please think on suggestions given by Redis group and we can try it.